# UITableViewCell not animating content after reloadSections with animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UITableView with 2 sections, first section have many controls and its ok, on second section I have a lot of cells having contents of results.

When I call realodSections in my table view, after make all fetches, I expect when my cell's appearing plays animation on label.

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Animating on:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[...]

if (indexPath.row==0) {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            cellBgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            cellBgView.frame = frame; // new frame
        } completion:nil];
    }
}


return cell;
}
```

Resulting: the animation only happens after three or two calls of method reloadSections